# Slow queries in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm using Mongoengine to perform query against MongoDB database and then save result as json file. My document definition looks like this:

```
class Foo(Document):
    # fields definitions goes here

    @queryset_manager
    def some_fields(self, queryset):
        return queryset.exclude('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
```

As you can see, I've created custom method to exclude some unnecessary fields from the query result. But the the whole process `query->count results->convert to json` is terribly slow. I've created some dummy logs to better explain my problem

```
    query_start = datetime.datetime.now()
    foos = Foo.some_fields.filter(**filter_dict)
    query_end = datetime.datetime.now()
    logger.debug(
        "%s || Query time: %s" % (str(datetime.datetime.now()), str((query_end - query_start).total_seconds())))
    counting_start = datetime.datetime.now()
    foos_count = foos.count()
    counting_end = datetime.datetime.now()
    logger.debug("%s || Foos count: %d in %f" % (
        str(datetime.datetime.now()), foos_count,(counting_end - counting_start).total_seconds(),
    ))
    serialization_start = datetime.datetime.now()
    json_response = foos.to_json()
    serialization_end = datetime.datetime.now()
    logger.debug("%s || Serialization time: %s" % (
        str(datetime.datetime.now()), str((serialization_end - serialization_start).total_seconds())))
```

The example output below

```
Query time: 0.098477
Foos count: 0 in 27.771622
Serialization time: 34.59575
```

I'm guessing that result from previous step is not being used by the next part. Am I right? Because I can't find any other explanation that converting empty result to json takes over half a minute. Or maybe I'm missing something? How can I change my code to perform these operations much faster?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe real query is in the second stage? You can to run your query in mongo console. If it will run around 30 seconds, you should think about indexes.